# Removing text wrapped in parentheses (including parentheses) from MySQL DB column using regex

Tags: mysql, regex

I have observations in a MySql database that have naming schemes like below

`foo (bar)`
`foo (bar 5) (foo)`
`foo (bar) bar (foobar) foo`

I want to delete the text from these observations that are in the parentheses (any character contained not just letters), inclusive of the parentheses so that the below remains

`foo`
`foo`
`foo bar foo`

Also realizing some left over whitespace might be annoying if there are multiple matches. Any help on the regex or functions is appreciated

Comment: Can the parens be nested?  Can they be unbalanced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you can use **REGEX_REPLACE**, this is a native function of mysql, I try with this code and worked for me, please let me know anything:

```
select regexp_replace(your_column,'([\(]*([\ [:alnum:]])+([\)]))','') as result from your_table;
```

good luck and if you need more information, this can help you:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace